# Filter Non Adjacent Multiple Column by matching range with another range

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I was searching for a while excel function currently using Excel 2021.
LAX worksheet from C6:R972 is the data range & total column are 16
Match column in Worksheet say test is A3:A1752 against worksheet LAX C6:C972.
I would like to get the result from E,K,Q,R column of LAX worksheet

```
=LET(z,LAX!C6:R972,l,A3:A1752,FILTER(FILTER(SORTBY(z,MATCH(INDEX(z,,16),l,)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(z))<=ROWS(l)),{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1}))
```

I am getting a wrong result: [File Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FXusWqa7fGjprFnSltz7Wc6V8ON2Qzd7/edit?usp=drivesdk&ouid=116118810195976517373&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Could you provide sample data and your expected outcome - otherwise it is hard to help. Reading [repro] should help you to improve your question.

Comment: I have mentioned the file link below formula in above.Kindly suggest me.

Comment: It's not good to share files. I won't download it - and it is not helpful for future users if you later remove it. Please read [ask] and [repro] - then we can help.

Comment: I am not going to delete in future.Be assured.